# Android, Gradle, product flavors and the manifest

Tags: android, gradle, android-build, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

In `build.gradle`, I have product flavors set up:

```
productFlavors
{
    AlternateFlavour
    {
        applicationId "com.myapp.alternateflavour"
    }
}
```

Then in the sourceSets section, I use different resource, assets and manifest directories for those flavours:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    AlternateFlavour {
        manifest.srcFile 'manifest-tmp/AlternateFlavour/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res-tmp/AlternateFlavour']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets-tmp/AlternateFlavour']
        }
   }
```

OK so far.

In that manifest being used by the flavor, which is in part automatically generated, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1010001"
    android:versionName="V1.1.0.1" >
```

but in the original manifest in the root project is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1010000"
    android:versionName="V1.1.0.DEBUG" >
```

This causes Gradle to fail:

```
Error:
    Attribute manifest@versionCode value=(1010001) from AndroidManifest.xml:4:5-28
    is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:4:5-28 value=(1010000).
Attributes of <manifest> elements are not merged.
```

**Why is it trying to merge with the original manifest at all, when I've specified it should look elsewhere?**

**And how can I stop this?**

I expect some will question why I'm doing it this way at all, or indeed why I'm not using the suggested flavor project structure. Well, I need a normal manifest to use outside of Gradle, e.g. for deploying from Eclipse (one thing at a time please!) and I also need versions to be injected by the build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be keeping in mind what @CommonsWare said in their answer, but for now, I've resolved this as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.myapp.myapp"
    tools:replace="android:versionName,android:versionCode"
    android:versionCode="1010001"
    android:versionName="V1.1.0.1" >
```

Note the two `tools` snippets.

I knew about this originally, but I was put off trying it, because the full Gradle error referred to three problems:

- versionCode
- versionName
- the Maps API key

all of which are auto-inserted. However it only proferred `tools:replace` as a suggestion for the last of those, so I got the impression that it wouldn't work on `manifest` attributes. In fact it does.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is it trying to merge with the original manifest at all, when I've specified it should look elsewhere?

You said *the flavor* manifest is elsewhere. The manifest merger process merges all relevant manifests:

- `main`
- the build type
- the product flavor(s)
- libraries

The manifest in `main` is always relevant.

> And how can I stop this?

You don't, insofar as the manifest in `main` is always relevant.

The best solution, in general, is to get rid of `versionCode` and `versionName` from *all* manifests, and set them in `build.gradle`, where you have full programmatic control.

The next-best solution is to move the `versionCode` and `versionName` out of the `main` manifest into the product flavor that you're not showing here. I have never seen anyone create just one product flavor, as AFAIK it's pointless — you can only ever build that one product flavor (as AFAIK there are no flavorless builds once you introduce flavors). Product flavors usually come in groups of 2+ (e.g., the `google` flavor that uses Play Services and the `standalone` flavor that doesn't). If the values in `main` are really for the non-`AlternateFlavour` flavor, move your `main` `version...` stuff there.

Beyond that, you're welcome to review [the documentation on the manifest merger process](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger) to see if you can put in the right directives to get what you want.

Comment: So first of all, there's loads of flavors here - I just tried to keep the given example simple. I can't (AFAIK) get away with removing the attributes from the original manifest because that's the one used by IDE deployment. However I could possibly create a third one, without the attributes, and have Gradle use that by default. Seems excessive!

Comment: @RobPridham: "that's the one used by IDE deployment" -- if you're using Android Studio, the Build Variants tool controls what is used by the IDE.

Comment: Indeed. Not there yet unfortunately - still using Eclipse & ADT for this development, for a variety of good (albeit less good over time) reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The Android official documentation will tell you why multiple manifest files will be merged during building process.

[Merge Multiple Manifest Files](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge)

**I have met the same problems while I want to get different flavors with different versionCode and versionName.When you want to do this,remove all versionCode and versionName from AndroidManifest.xml and try to do flavors in `build.gradle` file.**